# magento Get Base Url , Skin Url , Media Url , Js Url , Store Url and Current Url for secure

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am newbie to the `Magento`. I am developing a module. For that I have some `css` and`js` files that I want to display links. I currently have the links like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('module_tryouts/css/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.css');?>" media="all" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('module_tryouts/css/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.css');?>" media="all" />
```

But after going through some of the links I came to know that the link should be secure so that the module can be integrated with mazebridge.

http://jagdeepbanga.com/blog/magento-get-base-url-skin-url-media-url-js-url-store-url-and-current-url.html

http://www.webdosh.net/2011/04/magento-get-skin-url-get-media-url-get.html

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/7894/

http://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magebridge/integrations/1213-integrating-magebridge-with-other-magento-extensions

So can someone kindly tell me how to solve this issue? How to give a secure links to the files of js and css, images so that it can be integrated with mazebridge. Any help and suggestions will be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Below URL Access list

### Get URLs in CMS pages or static blocks

1. Base URL:

   ```
   {{base url=''}}
   ```
2. Store URL:

   ```
   {{store url='test.html'}}
   ```

   also only store URL

   ```
   {{store url=""}}
   ```
3. Media URL:

   only get media URL

   ```
   {{media url=''}}
   ```

   if you get some folder path

   ```
   {{media url='imagefolder/imagename.jpg'}}
   ```
4. Skin URL:

   ```
   {{skin url='images/imagename.jpg'}}
   ```

   only get skin URL

   ```
   {{skin url=''}}
   ```

### Get URLs in PHP files (incl. templates/PHTML)

1. Get Base Url  in magento:

   ```
   $baseurl = Mage::getBaseUrl();
   ```

   Get Base Url without index.php

   ```
   Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB); 

   // output: http://example.com/
   ```
2. Current Url

   ```
   $currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
   ```

   or

   ```
   $currentUrl = Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current' => true));
   ```

   or

   ```
   if (!in_array(Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName(), array('cms_index_noRoute', 'cms_index_defaultNoRoute'))) 
   {
       $currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
   }
   ```
3. Skin URL:

   ```
   $skinUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_SKIN);
   ```

   Unsecure Skin URL:

   ```
   $skinUrl = $this->getSkinUrl('images/imagename.jpg');
   ```

   Secure Skin URL:

   ```
   $this->getSkinUrl('images/imagename.gif', array('_secure'=>true));
   ```
4. Media URL

   ```
   $mediaUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
   ```

   or

   ```
   $mediaUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl('media');
   ```
5. Get Js URL:

   ```
   $jsUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_JS);
   ```

   or

   ```
   $jsUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl('js');
   ```
6. get store URL:

   ```
   $storeUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);
   ```
7. Get Home URL:

   ```
   $homeUrl= Mage::helper('core/url')->getHomeUrl();
   ```
8. Get Directory paths

   ```
   Mage::getBaseDir('design') // Get design directory path
   Mage::getBaseDir('code')   // Gives code directory file path
   Mage::getBaseDir('lib')    // Gives lib directory file path
   Mage::getBaseDir('skin')   // Gives skin directory file path
   Mage::getBaseDir('var')    // Gives var directory file path
   Mage::getBaseDir('cache')  // Gives cache directory file path
   Mage::getBaseDir('log')    // Gives log directory file path
   ```
9. Create module URL:

   ```
   Mage::getUrl('module/controller/action');
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go .

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('module_tryouts/css/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.css',array('_secure'=>true));?>" media="all" />

Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_JS,true); // this is secure for js in your comment.
```

Comment: then what about `Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_JS);` in case for js file

Comment: ok..If I have 10 different js files with different names then how to make them secure?

Comment: you already can use the method above it will give you js secure url !! and use the url as u want ???

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get the skin url is using this code snipped:

```
Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_SKIN);
```

why the downvote?

Comment: You probably got a down vote because of the culture of assuming the worst about new users and being unwelcoming on Stack Overflow. 
Your response worked perfectly to suit my needs. I needed the media url and replaced "URL_TYPE_SKIN" with "URL_TYPE_MEDIA". It works for that too.