# Knowing the current url you are in magento

Tags: magento

How can i trap my current url in magento

Comment: Possible duplicate of [magento Get Base Url , Skin Url , Media Url , Js Url , Store Url and Current Url for secure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18161360/magento-get-base-url-skin-url-media-url-js-url-store-url-and-current-url). Google turns up a few strong hits: [Magento get current url](http://www.google.com/search?q=magento+get+current+url).

Answer (score 1):

The normal approach is using the core/url helper:

```
Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
```

Take a look at [Mage_Core_Helper_Url](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Url.php) methods to see other ways to get this information.